# Проблема, связанная с туманом в unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

При использовании стандартного тумана в Unity, у меня появляются черные следы на плоскости, следы как будто теней. Я настраивал освещение и 3D модели на карте, но следы все же остались. Я был бы рад выслушать ваше мнение по поводу этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это материал который не обрабатывает `Fog`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я объезательно посмотрю что не так с этим материалом.

Comment: Вы были правы, проблема была именно из-за материала, благодарю за помощь.